# Using std::map inside switch case

Tags: c++, dictionary, switch-statement

I have this:

```
map<string,int> a;
int b;
```

And i'd like to make this:

```
switch(b)
{
  case a["someStr1"]:
  someCode1();
  break;

  case a["someStr2"]:
  someCode2();
  break;

  etc.
}
```

But it doesn't compiles. How to implement this correctly?

Comment: Probably the error when you compiled explains why.

Comment: switch only works on ordinals such as ints http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/switch-on-string/ you need to do a `==` comparison like `if  ("someStr1" == a) { do something; }`

Comment: can you add the error what you got during compilation

Comment: you may use a map of strings and function pointers, and just iterate over your map container to call each function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`switch` conditions need to be constants, so what you want to do here is not possible.

You're better off using some `if` statements.

Comment: @Fippo yea, that was the first thing that popped. It's just illegal.

Comment: Thanx, but is there exists a more elegant solution?

Comment: @Fippo you can have a map from `int` to a callback.

Comment: Sorry, that was misprint when typing question.

Comment: @Fippo look up callbacks. If you know what a callback is, it should be pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

`switch/case` are meant for constants (e.g., `enum`, `int`s etc.).
You can use the `map<>::iterator` to run through the values and compare with `b`.

```
for(map<string,int>::const_iterator it = a.begin(), end = a.end(); it != end; it++)
{
  if(it->second == b)
  {
    ...
    break;
  }
}
```

This way you can avoid the code duplication for comparison, if your `a` is large enough.

Also, you can explore the option of replacing `for` loop with [`for_each`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/).

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
Expression after `case` in a switch statement must be integral compile-time constant. So a literal (`42`), const int variable initialized with a literal (`const int x = 66` ... `case x:`) or enum value. And thats about it.

The reason this is so strict is efficiency. Compilers usually create labels for each `case` and if you know the value for each label at compile time, you can make some nice optimizations that avoid most of the overhead a normal code branching has.

In your case just go with if-else:

```
if(b == a["someStr1"]) {
    //...
} else if(b == a["someStr2"]) {
    //...
}   // and so on
```